# Attempting to fresh install Ubuntu dual boot rEFInd does not recognize live boot

Tags: partition, unix, dual-boot, efi

Attempted to do a fresh install of Ubuntu by following the procedure found here: [Clean install Ubuntu on a dual boot with Windows](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1587938)

I assumed that the fact that it was for Vista instead of OS X was inconsequential. My base OS is Yosemite.

Now when rEFInd starts up, I still see the option for OS X and Ubuntu but no option for installing Ubuntu.

When I click the Ubuntu option it says "error: no such partition. entering recovery mode"

Any ideas on how to resolve this? Any and all input would be greatly appreciated!

---

UPDATE:

I attempted to start up GParted again to see if I missed something and now rEFInd isn't seeing it either? Don't know if this is useful info? Does Gparted depend on the presence of Ubuntu?

---

FURTHER UPDATE:

1) Base OS: Yosemite

2) What media device you are installing Ubuntu from: DVD+R

3) Your method before it stopped working: Not sure exactly what you mean by method. I was attempting to get my WiFi working (It works for OS X but didn't work for Ubuntu, GParted, or Tails. but I'll cross that bridge later). I used rEFInd to load it, and used GParted to delete it.

Comment: You make it very unclear as to which base operating system you have. Please indicate the following:
1) Base OS.
2) What media device you are installing Ubuntu from.
3) Your method before it stopped working.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out! Yosemite is my base os. I've also added that detail  to the main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to my answer to [another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/213695/how-to-properly-install-kali-linux-on-macbook-air-dual-boot-with-el-capitan/213785?noredirect=1#comment258901_213785#answer-213785) involving similar difficulties. The method is the exact same, except you should skip step 4 and use the Ubuntu ISO instead.

Before attempting anything though, remove all traces of your previous failed installation attempts from the Mac.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Can't tell you how grateful I am that there a such wise ppl or there willing to lend a helping hand. Thanks again

Comment: However I do have one more question pertaining to you answer about WiFi. When the wiki says that the package has to be built on a system with the same kernel version, does that mean if I'm trying to get WiFi on a system running ubuntu 15.04, then the package must be built on that same version?  I'm guessing since I don't have WiFi, I need to go out and purchase a thunderbolt? Or am I mistaken about the meaning and I can build the package on the osx system?

Comment: To enable Wi-Fi you must build the package on Ubuntu 15.04 if that is the OS where you lack Wi-Fi connectivity. You don't need to purchase anything, you can _cURL_ and _unpack_ it on OS X and then transfer the **broadcom-wl** folder to the Ubuntu partition across boots with a USB stick. From there you can build the driver.